# reading complex data in pyspark into dataframe

Tags: arrays, pyspark, complex-data-types

I was trying to create a spark dataframe, But there was some issue, can some one help me where it was going wrong?

```
schema = StructType([StructField("array_str1", ArrayType(StringType()),False)
                     ,StructField("array_str2", ArrayType(StringType()),False)
                     ,StructField("str1", StringType(), False)
                    ]) 
array_str1 = [["Size", "Color"]],[["Size", "Color"]],[["Size", "Color"]] 
array_str2 = [["M", "Black"]],[["L", "White"]],[["M", "Red"]] 
names = [['John']], [['Tom']], [['Matteo']]

df = spark.createDataFrame([array_str1
                            ,array_str2
                            ,names
                           ], schema) 
df.show(10,False)
```

But I am getting dataframe as below.

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|array_str1     |array_str2     |str1           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|[[Size, Color]]|[[Size, Color]]|[[Size, Color]]|
|[[M, Black]]   |[[L, White]]   |[[M, Red]]     |
|[[John]]       |[[Tom]]        |[[Matteo]]     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

But I need dataframe to be created as below

```
+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
| str1      | array_of_str1        | array_of_str2  |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
| John      | [Size, Color]        | [M, Black]     |
| Tom       | [Size, Color]        | [L, White]     |
| Matteo    | [Size, Color]        | [M, Red]       |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------+
```

Can someone please help me where it was going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Transpose your data with `zip`:

```
array_str1 = ["Size", "Color"], ["Size", "Color"], ["Size", "Color"]
array_str2 = ["M", "Black"], ["L", "White"], ["M", "Red"]
names = 'John', 'Tom', 'Matteo'

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(array_str1, array_str2, names), schema)

df.show(10, False)

+-------------+----------+------+
|array_str1   |array_str2|str1  |
+-------------+----------+------+
|[Size, Color]|[M, Black]|John  |
|[Size, Color]|[L, White]|Tom   |
|[Size, Color]|[M, Red]  |Matteo|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

Comment: Zip usually zips equal number of lists, are we transposing using zip here?

Comment: zip can work on non equal length lists too. It's just the extra elements are discarded. If you want to keep them, you can use `itertools.zip_longest`